# Django database cache queryset methods

Tags: python, django, caching

I have a database cache for my django application.

I can do the following to get multiple cache rows from the table:

```
cache.get_many(cache_keys_list)
```

This is a sequential query retrieving one record at a time:

[image]

Is it possible to have a queryset method for a database cache like would for any other model object to retrieve multiple values?

Comment: what version of Django you use

Comment: also take note that database cache is rarely helpful, never used it in production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using Django version prior to release of following [optimization](https://github.com/django/django/commit/abd0ad7681422d7c40a5ed12cc3c9ffca6b88422)

You could update Django , use following function as snippet or create custom MyDatabaseCache from new code

current source is [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/efc3e32d6d7fb9bb41be73b80c8607b653c1fbd6/django/core/cache/backends/db.py#L53)

Comment: Thanks, just realized I was looking at the 1.11 source code and it has been updated since.